# Angularjs directive with dynamic template and transclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude, angular-template

I'm trying add a dynamic template and met problem with transclude.

This is dynamic template function:

```
var getTemplate = function(contentType){
      var template = '<button style="cursor: pointer;">' + contentType + '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude></button>'
      return template;
    };
```

And this is code to call the dynamic template and update transclude:

```
element.html(getTemplate(attr.firstname));

transclude($scope.$parent, function (clone, $scope) {
          element.children().append(clone);
        });
```

Look at full code here
https://plnkr.co/edit/cQBeiDkEb8KwhrFWb8iR?p=preview

View the console i see this notice: angular.js:13920TypeError: transclude is not a function

The result should be included: Go button.

Go button code here:

```
<my-button firstname="John"><button style="cursor: pointer;"><i style="color: green;">Go</i></button></my-button>
```

Please help me to fix it.

This is docs i used: [docs](http://www.spaprogrammer.com/2015/01/angularjs-transclusion-with-nested.html)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Transclusion has changed multiple times since that article was written;  The syntax from 2015 won't work with more current versions of Angular, and most likely the logic won't be what you expect either.  You should re-think what you are trying to accomplish and post a question asking how to accomplish your goal, rather than how to solve an error from an outdated article;  Unless, that is, you use *exactly the same* version of angular as the article in question, which is probably not a great idea....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the plunkr the path to angular script was not found. Changing to `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>` and i see the error "angular.js:13920TypeError: transclude is not a function ..."

Comment: have you checked the console????i too face this and i changed that with my cdn then i got proper output but in console i got the following error " Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! No parent directive that requires a transclusion found. Element: <ng-transclude>"

Comment: Yes, that is an error, i have updated new url for angular, but ng translude showing errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed done this problem.

this is new example code:
HTML CODE:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<my-directive title="nguyen hai dang">
<button>some button</button>
<a href="#">and a link</a>
</my-directive>
</div>
```

JS CODE:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.log=[];
}

myApp.directive("myDirective", function(){
    return{
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
        transclude: true,
    scope: {
            title: "@"
          },
        template: "<div class=\"something\" ng-transclude>{{title}} </div>"
    };
});
```

Check code here [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/7LRDS/700/)